# Microsoft Security Essentials for a business

Tags: windows-xp, anti-virus, license, ms-security-essentials

This is 2 questions really -

1. Am I allowed to install Microsoft Security Essentials 1.0 in a business of 200 - 300 users?
2. Is Microsoft Security Essentials 1.0 adequate protection (real-time scanning, updates etc)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer 1: Unfortunately, no.  The [license](http://www.microsoft.com/Security_essentials/eula.aspx) specifically states in the first bullet point in section 1

> You may install and use any number of copies of the software on your devices in your household for use by people who reside there or for use in your home-based small business.

Answer 2: It sounds good to me, though I haven't looked at any lab comparisons yet.  I have started recommending it to co-workers for their home computers -- it's a lot better than nothing!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers given her, just a small remark:

From benchmarks that I've seen MSE seems to give a very good level of protection, almost as good as any other anti-virus product on the market. Apparently you need have no fears on that account.

Answer (score 3):

"Microsoft Security Essentials is NOT supported for businesses of any kind. Not only that, but it is licensed for consumer use only, and carries similar license wording to Office Home & Student. Commercial or for-profit institutions must pay for the software. AVG and Avast have similar licensing."

I will ask MSFT if he is right. For now, all I can say is the person who sent is a MS partner and usually has good info to pass along... MJ

Source: http://talkback.zdnet.com/5208-12558-0.html?forumID=1&threadID=69120&messageID=1320939

Answer (score 3):

I just want to bring some precisions regarding the licensing and correct what I think are erroneous statements from other answers (e.g. "Microsoft Security Essentials is NOT supported for businesses of any kind"): Microsoft Security Essentials may be used in a business environment under the following condition:

> "b. **Small Business**. If you operate a small business, then
>   you may install and use the software
>   on up to ten (10) devices in your
>   business."

The above sentenced is quoted from the below article:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security_essentials/eula.aspx

Comment: +1 - yes supported for 10 or less business systems, but I will comment that if you have any kind of public liability then it would be foolish to use a non-centrally managed solution.  For example, if you got hacked through a trojan or something similar and your customer base got leaked, one of the things you will be asked in legal proceedings is whether you took reasonable precautions and how can you prove this?  With MSE you can't, it is only your word that you installed it and kept it up to date on all workstations.

Comment: interesting comment.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. Depends on your definition of 'adequate'. It does real-time scanning and auto-updates, and is reportedly very good on not reporting false positives. For 200-300 desktops you might want something with more centralised control over rollouts and so on.

Comment: We use Active Directory with our network, could that not rollout MSE

Comment: 1. Yes? I doubt that, given Randy's answer at http://superuser.com/questions/52663/microsoft-security-essentials-for-a-business/52691#52691

Answer (score 1):

You can install MSE on whatever computers you want, as long as it meets the minimum requirements. However, it does not work with any Windows Server flavors. MSE seems good enough for me; all the reviews I have read have given it nothing but praise.

The disadvantage of MSE is that you have no centralized management of the antivirus, like you'd have with [Forefront Client Security](http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/clientsecurity/). With such a large number of PCs it might be a problem.

Comment: Incorrect: From Microsofts License. 

Use. You may install and use any number of copies of the software on your devices in your household for use by people who reside there or for use in your home-based small business. If you install it on computers running in a business running from a location that is not the owners house you are breaking the license, and the law.

Answer (score 1):

Just to address question #2 - I have been running MSE with religious updates and was infected last week with a GDI vulnerability attack that nearly forced a total wipe. I'm re-evaluating the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

About point 2, MSE is just a scanner, it has no prevention feature against zero-days malware and exploits which are the most prevalent threats.